# Samba share on rpi/Linux is reporting SD card space rather than HDD space in Windows

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, samba, size

The samba config should be pointing directly to the mount point I have created for the two external HDDs, yet it still reports in Windows as 116GB (my OS SD card size on the Pi).

/etc/fstab (DEVICEUUID being the actual UUID of the HDD)

```
UUID=DEVICEUUID /usb1/share ext4 defaults,auto,users,$users,rw,nofail
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf (showing only share1 for readability)

```
[Share]
comment = Private storage
path = /usb1/share
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
read only = no
```

I have also run the following commands on the /usb1 and /usb2 directories

```
sudo chown -R pi usb1
sudo chmod -R 0775 usb1
```

findmnt --target /usb1/share returns

```
/      /dev/mmcblk0p2 ext4   rw,noatime
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `findmnt --target /usb1/share` return? (Please add this to your question. Don't reply in the comments.)

Comment: What's this `UUID=INSERT` in the `/etc/fstab` entry? That's not a valid UUID. On that same line, what do you expect `$users` to do?

Comment: "_I have also run chown and chmod commands on the /usb1 and /usb2 directories_" please provide the actual command you used

Comment: findmnt added & chmod/chown commands added, as well as clarifying the UUID=INSERT bit. I have no idea what $users is supposed to do in the fstab truth be told

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your Samba share is reporting the SD card root filesystem disk space is because that's where it's pointing. The directory `/usb1/share` is on this root filesystem.

The chances are that the entry in `/etc/fstab` is failing to mount because it's invalid. You can check this by running

```
mount /usb1/share
findmnt --target /usb1/share
```

The first command attempts to mount the filesystem. The second identifies the actual filesystem holding the specified directory; it shouldn't be `/`.

Try this `/etc/fstab` entry

```
UUID=DEVICEUUID  /usb1/share  ext4  defaults  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick